# CakePHP 3.10 -> 4.x Upgrade - Rector won't start

Tags: php, cakephp, rector

I am in the process of upgrading a site from CakePHP 3.10.0 to CakePHP 4.x using the [4.x Upgrade Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html). I have been successful up until the point where you need to run the following commands:

```
bin/cake upgrade rector --rules phpunit80 <path/to/app/tests>
bin/cake upgrade rector --rules cakephp40 <path/to/app/src>
```

I skipped the first command as I do not do unit testing (*yet!*). When I run the second command, it just hangs. There is no output at all from this command. I have let it sit for hours but it does nothing. I added `-v` to the command and finally got some output but it still hangs:

```
$ bin/cake upgrade rector --rules cakephp40 ../vintage-lib/src -v
Detecting autoload file for /mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/src
-> Checking /mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/src/vendor/autoload.php
-> Checking /mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/vendor/autoload.php
-> Found /mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/vendor/autoload.php
Running /mnt/d/Programming/PHP/upgrade/vendor/bin/rector process  --autoload-file='/mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/vendor/autoload.php' --config='/mnt/d/Programming/PHP/upgrade/config/rector/cakephp40.php' --working-dir='/mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/src' '/mnt/d/Programming/PHP/vintage-lib/src'
```

I have tried running this in Windows, WSL and even in a Linux VM - the result remains the same which makes me believe it is something with my code or a config file. I tried to run the command on each of my plugins but I get the same result.

I have also run and fixed all errors and warnings from codesniffer but it makes no difference.

I am at a loss as I don't know where to check next. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should not skip steps, they may provide valuable information/hints.
Also you can have a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097953/cakephp-upgrade-from-3-9-x-to-4-0-bin-cake-upgrade-rector-rules-phpunit80-ha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097953/cakephp-upgrade-from-3-9-x-to-4-0-bin-cake-upgrade-rector-rules-phpunit80-ha) , it  could help

Comment: @MarcelPreda The only step I skipped was for running rector on the unit tests because I have no tests directory so that command will likely immediately fail because the directory does not exist. Also, I saw that question already and it does not apply as that user is getting output from the rector command and I am not. I have also stated that I already ran some of the things they did like codesniffer.

Comment: maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260091/cakephp-upgrade-from-3-6-x-to-4-0-missing-template-exception/60260874#60260874

Answer (score 0):

I undertook an upgrade from 3.4 to 4.0 following the migration guide to a T, going through each minor upgrade and I still had the same issue with rector hanging.

Solution was, there is an Out of the Box PagesController that has been changed at some point between 3.4 and 3.10. I had to replace it with the version from the skeleton app (https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.x/src/Controller/PagesController.php) in order for rector to pass.

If that's not your problem, try running rector one directory at a time to identify the problematic file. You can find the directory listing like:
$ find /path/to/app/src/ -type d